# I need to take this SQL query to a query with GORM

Tags: sql, postgresql, go, go-gorm

I have this SQL query.

```
select c.id,
       c.title as collection,
               (select json_agg(g2.*)
                from (select g.id,
                             g.title,
                             g.price,
                             g.description,
                             (select json_agg(items.*)
                              from (select id, size, color, quantity, images
                                    from items t
                                    where t.id = any (g.items_id)) items) as items
                      from "groups" g
                      where g.id = any (c.group_id)) g2) "group"
from collections c where c.publication_date <= now();
```

And this is the modeling that I have in the database.

```
    create table collections (
    id serial primary key NOT null,
    title varchar (20) unique not null,
    group_id int[],
    publication_date timestamp not null,
    created_at timestamp NOT null default now(),
    updated_at timestamp NOT null default now(),
    created_by int NOT NULL,
    updated_by int NOT NULL
    );

insert into collections(title, group_id, publication_date, created_by, updated_by)
values
('verano', '{1,2}',  now(),  1, 1),
('premium', '{2}', now(), 1, 1),
('moda 2023','{3}', now(), 1, 1),
('moda 2024','{4}', now(), 1, 1);

create table "groups" (
    id serial primary key NOT null,
    title varchar (50) unique not null,
    items_id int[],
    price float8 not null,
    description varchar (250),
    created_at timestamp NOT null default now(),
    updated_at timestamp NOT null default now(),
    created_by int  NOT NULL,
    updated_by int  NOT NULL
);

insert into "groups"(title, items_id, price, description ,created_by, updated_by)
values
('Blusa De Dama Mikey Mouse', '{1,2}', 5.99,'Blusa de dama con micro durazno, distintos colores.' , 1, 1),
('Sueter Tricolor', '{3,4}', 13.85,'Blusa de dama con micro durazno, distintos colores.' , 1, 1),
('Mono Adidas', '{5,6}', 17.99,'Blusa de dama con micro durazno, distintos colores.' , 1, 1),
('Franela Apolo', '{}', 8.99,'Franela Apolo, distintos colores.' , 1, 1);

create table items (
  id serial primary key NOT null,
  "size" char not null,
  color varchar (10) not null,
  quantity int not null,
  images text[] not null,
  created_at timestamp NOT null default now(),
  updated_at timestamp NOT null default now(),
  created_by int  NOT NULL,
  updated_by int  NOT NULL
  );

insert into items (size, color, quantity, images, created_by, updated_by)
values
('U', 'Negro', 150, '{none}', 1, 1),
('S', 'Blanco', 150, '{none}', 1, 1),
('M', 'Gris', 150, '{none}', 1, 1),
('U', 'Gris', 220, '{none}', 1, 1),
('S', 'Verde', 220, '{none}', 1, 1),
('M', 'Negro', 220, '{none}', 1, 1);
```

The query above works fine with that model when I do it in DBeaver, but I don't know how to do it in Go with GORM.

I tried this way but the Group data came back empty.

```
err := p.DB.WithContext(ctx).Raw("select c.id, c.title, (select json_agg(g2.*) from (select g.id, g.title, g.price, g.description (select json_agg(items.*) from (select id, size, color, quantity, images from items t where t.id = any (g.items_id)) items) as items from groups g where g.id = any (c.group_id)) g2) as group from collections c where c.publication_date <= now()").
Scan(&products).
Error
```

This is the result I get.

```
[
    {
        "ID": 1,
        "Title": "verano",
        "PublicationDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
        "Group": null,
        "CreatedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
        "UpdatedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
        "CreatedBy": 0,
        "UpdatedBy": 0
    },
    {
        "ID": 2,
        "Title": "premium",
        "PublicationDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
        "Group": null,
        "CreatedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
        "UpdatedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
        "CreatedBy": 0,
        "UpdatedBy": 0
    },
    {
        "ID": 3,
        "Title": "moda 2023",
        "PublicationDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
        "Group": null,
        "CreatedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
        "UpdatedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
        "CreatedBy": 0,
        "UpdatedBy": 0
    },
    {
        "ID": 4,
        "Title": "moda 2024",
        "PublicationDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
        "Group": null,
        "CreatedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
        "UpdatedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
        "CreatedBy": 0,
        "UpdatedBy": 0
    }
]
```

And this is the model I am using in my backend.

```
type Collection struct {
    ID              int64
    Title           string
    PublicationDate time.Time
    Group           []Group `gorm:"embedded"`
    CreatedAt       time.Time
    UpdatedAt       time.Time
    CreatedBy       uint
    UpdatedBy       uint
}

type Group struct {
    ID          int64
    TitleG      string
    Price       float64
    Description string
    Items       []Item `gorm:"embedded"`
    CreatedAt   time.Time
    UpdatedAt   time.Time
    CreatedBy   uint
    UpdatedBy   uint
}

type Item struct {
    ID        int64
    Size      string
    Color     string
    Quantity  int
    Images    []string
    CreatedAt time.Time
    UpdatedAt time.Time
    CreatedBy uint
    UpdatedBy uint
}
```

I look forward to your comments. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the nested JSON with gorm, you'll have to define the relationship between your models and then use the `Preload` function to load the associated data. Try modifying your backend model this way;

```
type Collection struct {
    ID              int64
    Title           string
    PublicationDate time.Time
    Groups          []Group `gorm:"foreignKey:CollectionID"`
    CreatedAt       time.Time
    UpdatedAt       time.Time
    CreatedBy       uint
    UpdatedBy       uint
}

type Group struct {
    ID          int64
    Title       string
    Price       float64
    Description string
    Items       []Item `gorm:"foreignKey:GroupID"`
    CreatedAt   time.Time
    UpdatedAt   time.Time
    CreatedBy   uint
    UpdatedBy   uint
}

type Item struct {
    ID        int64
    Size      string
    Color     string
    Quantity  int
    Images    []string
    CreatedAt time.Time
    UpdatedAt time.Time
    CreatedBy uint
    UpdatedBy uint
}
```

Then you should use the `Preload` function in your code:

```
err := p.DB.Preload("Groups.Items").Where("publication_date <= now()").Find(&products).Error
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
```